# Create an 8.5x11 or A4 Letter Size Page with Tables for Text

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

I would like to create an A4 or 8.5x11 page that would look like what I have attached. One page has a 3" top margin, 2 vertical lines, 1" margin left/right with line numbers on the left., and two 2" cells at the top below the 3" margin. Each page has numbers and footers.

As far as I could get HTML and the CSS:

```css
body {
  background: rgb(204, 204, 204);
}

page {
  background: white;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

page[size="A4"] {
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm;
}

page[size="A4"][layout="landscape"] {
  width: 29.7cm;
  height: 21cm;
}

@media print {
  body,
  page {
    background: white;
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: 0;
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <page size="A4"></page>
  <page size="A4"></page>
  <page size="A4">PAGE</page>
  <page size="A4"></page>
</body>
```

[image: Page 1 A4 Title Page]

[image: Page 2 A4 All Following Pages]

Comment: Do you want this to for printing, or just to mimic pages? For example, trying to do A4 on a phone screen doesn't really make sense. For printing see [@page CSS docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page).

Comment: I would like to just mimic pages its' not for anything like a phone just to display as a fixed size page.

Comment: Your footer on the first page seems to be within the vertical lines, but not on the second page. What's the difference / is that correct?

Comment: Do you mean the 4 inch gap above the header of the first page should appear on the second as well?

Comment: I do apologize you are correct, the first page and following pages. The footer should match and begin at the end of the vertical line numbers. The first page header should be 3" all remaining sides and bottom set to 1"  <page> is css>  I will repost the image to better reflect the idea. thank you

Comment: I have been reading and viewing many different examples, in my updated example,  it is a bit different in layout and text. Yes these are similar, thank you, for that option, and opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How's this looking?

```css
body { background: rgb(204,204,204); }
.page {
    --page-inset-side: 1in; /* left/right */
    --page-inset-ends: 1in; /* top/bottom */

    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;

    background: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    
    padding: var(--page-inset-ends) var(--page-inset-side);
    
    /* footer-related stuff */
    --footer-height: 2in;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.page.portraitA4 {
    --page-side-numbers: '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25';
    --page-height: 29.7cm;
    width: 21cm;
    height: var(--page-height);
}
.page.landscapeA4 {
    --page-side-numbers: '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15';
    --page-height: 21cm;
    width: 29.7cm;
    height: var(--page-height);
}

.page::before, .page::after {
    --page-vertical-line: black 0.1cm solid;

    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: var(--page-inset-side);
    position: absolute;
    top: var(--page-inset-ends);
    
    /* vertical line length */
    height: calc(
        var(--page-height)
        - (2 * var(--page-inset-ends))
        - 2.1cm /* space for footer */
    );
}

.page::before {
    content: var(--page-side-numbers);
    border-right: var(--page-vertical-line);
    left: 0;
    
    line-height: 0.9cm;
    font-weight: bold;
    
    --numbers-inset: 0.3in;
    /* leave no room for content so that we guarantee overflow and wrapping */
    padding-left: calc(var(--page-inset-side) - var(--numbers-inset));
    padding-right: var(--numbers-inset);
}

.page::after {
    content: '';
    border-left: var(--page-vertical-line);
    right: 0;
}

.pageContent {
    margin-inline: 0.4cm;
    margin-top: 2in;
}

.pageFooter {
    font-size: 9pt;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 5cm auto 6.3cm;
    margin-inline: 0.5cm;
}
.pageFooter p {
    margin: 0;
}
.pageFooter > :nth-child(2) {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="page portraitA4">
        <div class="pageContent">Page 1</div>
        <div class="pageFooter">
            <div>
                <p>Ut nec felis non quam dictum ultrices.</p>
                <p>Nullam gravida nulla ac est laoreet gravida.</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                3
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>Ut nec felis non quam dictum ultrices.</p>
                <p>Nullam gravida nulla ac est laoreet gravida.</p>
                <p>Vestibulum tempus tellus egestas, tempor justo
                   interdum, accumsan nisl.</p>
                <p>Sed mollis quam sed faucibus condimentum.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="page landscapeA4">
        <div class="pageContent">Page 2</div>
        <div class="pageFooter">
            <div>
                <p>Ut nec felis non quam dictum ultrices.</p>
                <p>Nullam gravida nulla ac est laoreet gravida.</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                3
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>Ut nec felis non quam dictum ultrices.</p>
                <p>Nullam gravida nulla ac est laoreet gravida.</p>
                <p>Vestibulum tempus tellus egestas, tempor justo
                   interdum, accumsan nisl.</p>
                <p>Sed mollis quam sed faucibus condimentum.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: Yes, I have been working on the base you have provided.  Nice job looks great.  it helped me understand the placement of the DIV and text for the entire page. Thanks.